# combined GUI and command-line OS X app

Tags: macos

Is it possible to create a single Mac OS X app that can be run strictly from the *nix command-line (using stdin/stdout, from the Terminal console or via ssh, etc.), but also be launchable from an app icon and using the Mac GUI for all user interaction (no Terminal required)?  If so, how?

I can already achieve something like this using two executables, one a GUI front-end for the other, with pipes, sockets, shared memory, or Applescript (et.al.) for communication.  This question is whether I can do this using a single executable and single app process space.

Is there a way to do this without passing a new command-line argument to the command-line executable? (as there are legacy issues related to use of the command-line app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure whether this'll work, but the documentation for the `LSEnvironment` key in `Info.plist` seems to indicate that the specified environment variables will only be defined when your application is launched by Finder.

If you were to define a variable in `LSEnvironment` (let's call it `MYAPP_GUI`) and check its value at launch, it should exist when using Finder and not when using Terminal. That'll tell you whether or not to show GUI or use stdio

Comment: This is a great idea, I haven't thought of. However, could some nasty guy read my info-plist and imitate that Env var when running from shell?

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Even if someone can mess with it, this is my preferred method, unless there is a more robust way (some API from Apple) to tell you the context of your launch.

Comment: Also... your answer works also when launched via "open" in the command line, from "Login Items", from "LaunchPad" and all other variations of launch that are "user-like" (meaning - done by LaunchServices). all other "programmatic/command-line/launchd" launches won't have the env-var. This is my preferred answer.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for, I believe, is a way to determine if you are launched from the GUI or the command line. A simple way would be to get your parent process identifier. If you're a GUI process, you are started by launchd (the user session launchd). If you are a command line, then a shell or script has started you (at any rate, NOT launchd).

Now, how to do so - a simple way would be to use the proc_info system call (#336), which is conveniently wrapped by libproc (check `<libproc.h>`. Specifically, you would want proc_bsdinfo (see `<sys/proc_info.h>`) which has the pbi_ppid field to specify your parent (and pbi_comm of the parent would tell you its name - to see if it's launchd). You could implement command line functionality by checking your parent right before you go into `NSApplicationMain`.

(As in other answers, your binary will end up in your `.app/Contents/MacOS/<binary>`, so yes, a symlink makes sense)

Comment: I have a issue with this technique (using getppid() to determine if this is a "UI" launch or "shell" launch, since I need my "command-line" to run as a launchDaemon... and so, its parent pid will be 1 even (especially when) intended to run as a command-line with no UI. I need another trick

Answer (score 1):

Although @3doubloons provided the correct answer, I'd still like to share my code snippet that demonstrates this.

First, add an `LSEnvironment` key to your Info.plist. Its value is a Dictionary of env-var-names (as keys) and their string (only strings allowed!) values. in my case, I added the `LaunchUI` key, with the value `"Yup"`

[image]

Then, my main() function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int status = -1;
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        do {
            NSProcessInfo *procInfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];

            // deterine "UI" launch versus "command-line
            id uiEnvVar = [[procInfo environment] objectForKey:@"LaunchUI"];
            if([uiEnvVar isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [uiEnvVar isEqualToString:@"Yup"] ) {    
                status = NSApplicationMain(argc, argv); //launch app normally with UI
                break;
            }
            
            id arguments = [procInfo arguments];
            if (arguments == nil) {
                printUsage();
                break;
            }
            if ([arguments count] == 1 || [arguments containsObject:@"-h"] || [arguments containsObject:@"-help"]) {
                printUsage();
                status = 0;
                break;
            }
            
            //process further arguments
            if(processArgs(arguments) == NO) {
                printUsage();
                break;
            }

            // kick off protection.

            if(YES != do_work()) {
                break;
            }
            
            status = 0; //

            // if your command-line should stay alive and handle events - you can do the following to block it from exiting.
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        } while(false);
    }
    return status;
}
```

I think that kind'a covers it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Just add a switch `--command-line` to the program.  Start the normal GUI unless `--command-line` is passed as an argument when running.

```
./myprog --command-line
```

That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say the question is how to implement something like a `--command-line` switch in code.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn If that's the case, I suggest the question to be renamed to "Explain basic logic for me please".  The question was "Is it possible?"  Unless the OP edits his question or tells us what programming language he's using, I'd say this answer is sufficient.

Comment: Good answer, but see the edit for additional requirements.  Turning on/off stdio vs. GUI processing after launch is not the issue.

Comment: +1 I agree.  I guess I provided extensive elaboration then. :)  Really though, I agree, we need more info from the OP, like what programming language is he using and maybe some sample code from his `main()` function.

Comment: Xcode built near-identical generic Objective C apps (two versions currently, one using stdio, one using Cocoa).  I would prefer to distribute one executable instead of two, if possible.

Comment: The GUI application is not an executable. It's a directory. Inside that there are a lot of things, including the executable. You can use the standard parameters of the main function to check if you have to start the gui or no as suggested by @ZnArK and then distribute only the app bundle. As for "no new argument", I can only suggest you play with the unix environment instead or you use a script to add the argument (it's a separate file but not a separate binary and could be created by the application upon first execution if you do not want to distribute it).

Answer (score 0):

This is to be taken with a grain of salt as this is what I'd do in a .Net app, I think the idea can be achieved in other languages on other platforms.

I would create a console application that then still uses all the GUI classes. When the program starts, based on whatever criteria determines if it's a GUI instance rather than a command line instance I either start up a GUI or I start into the command line interface accordingly.

The main thing is that you have some condition that determines when you want to show a GUI instead of a command line. Maybe through a system variable about the session (is it an ssh session, then command line, otherwise GUI).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it won't be possible in the way you expect it to be. GUI OSX apps are actually application bundles, i.e. they are actually directories containing *lots* of resources besides the actual executable. You certainly *cannot* execute these bundles in a shell as if they were command-line executables (e.g. you can't do `./MyApplication.app --some-option` on your shell prompt, since your shell does not know how to execute a directory), though you probably know that you *can* run them as GUI via `open MyApplication.app`. Now, you *can* reach the actual executable inside the bundle, and it *might* be possible to get *that* executable to work as a CLI executable — speaking out of my ass here as I have no actual experience with the Xcode tools and its build system, but might be possible to have the actual executable work in both CLI and GUI invocation.

Still, that wouldn't be very useful, since those executables are buried inside the application bundle and generally not directly reachable in a shell (i.e. they're certainly not in your $PATH, so you'll have to invoke them as something like `./MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/actualbinaryname`). The usual approach I've seen in the wild is to provide a separate CLI executable bundled with your application, which usually gets installed in a suitable location (e.g. /usr/local/bin) by an installer or through clicking a button in the app preferences. Those CLI executables take care of interfacing with the GUI app, if that is what you intend to do (it is not clear from your question).

Comment: Yes.  I do this now with 2 executables.  A symlink in /usr/local/bin would waste less disk space if the 2 executables could be somehow built as one (with suitable internal conditional code, which is mostly already there for GUI vs. stdio).

Comment: There is no need for dual executables, or symlinks. Only you main() function shuold decide whether to call NSApplicationMain(argc, argv); or preform your command-line code.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I am missing the point, but if you are using objective-C, isn't part of the answer to use the NSProcessInfo class in objective-C and examine the 'arguments' variable to determine if any arguments have been passed, and then make up your mind in code about what to do next?

Comment: What if he needs no arguments, or is being launched from "Login Items" or from the Doc? the root difference is being launched via  MacOS's "LaunchServices" or otherwise. Currently the best answer is via the LSEnvironment key in Info.plist below.